# Group by a sequence in data frame in R

Tags: r, split, group-by, duplicates, data.table

I have data frame, I need to divide into 3 groups based on month.

- Group 1: month 1,2 & medication change at month 2
- Group 2: month 1,2,3 & medication change at month 3
- Group 3: month 1,2,3,4,up & medication change at month 4

Count frequency, mean, SE of each medication (total 5 medications) they use by 3 groups.

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8)
month <- c(1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,4)
med <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,6,6,7,7,7,3,3,3,3,1,1,5,5,5,5)
mean <-  c(4,6,5,2,3,7,5,7,1,3,6,7,5,2,3,3,3,3,3,5,6,7,8,1,6,4,5,6,7)
df <- data.frame(ID,month,med,mean)
df

    ID month med mean
1   1     1   1    4
2   1     2   1    6
3   2     1   2    5
4   2     2   2    2
5   2     3   2    3
6   2     4   3    7
7   3     1   4    5
8   3     2   4    7
9   3     3   4    1
10  3     4   4    3
11  3     5   4    6
12  4     1   1    7
13  4     2   1    5
14  4     3   1    2
15  5     1   6    3
16  5     2   6    3
17  5     3   7    3
18  5     4   7    3
19  5     5   7    3
20  6     1   3    5
21  6     2   3    6
22  6     3   3    7
23  6     4   3    8
24  7     1   1    1
25  7     2   1    6
26  8     1   5    4
27  8     2   5    5
28  8     3   5    6
29  8     4   5    7
```

I have 8 ID

- ID = 1, should in Group 1, they use Med = 1.
- ID = 2, should in Group 3, Med = 2, if you check Med, they use 2 and
  3, but as soon as they keep at least first of 2, I set them in group 3. If they change Med at month 3, I set them group 2. If they change med at month 2, I set them in group 1.
- ID = 3, should in Group 3. Med = 4
- ID = 4, should in Group 2. Med = 1
- ID = 5, should in Group 2. Med = 6
- ID = 6, should in Group 3. Med = 3
- ID = 7, should in Group 1. Med = 1
- ID = 8, should in Group 3. Med = 5

My data is large, I try to use data.table but I don't know how to split it.

Comment: Learn how to use `tapply` it will be your best friend in `R`.

Comment: I don't see how your desired output fit with your condition logic. It doesn't seem like the group has anything to do Medication change. For example group 5, it changes the medication at month 3 but still group 3?

Comment: Sorry, it s supposed to Group 2 @Psidom

Comment: Is there a guarantee that within each ID, the month is always a sequential, i.e `1,2`, `1,2,3` but not `1,3` or `1,3,3`?

Comment: yes@Psidom, it's squence, 1,2 or 1,2,3, or 1,2,3,4 and more

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your logic correctly, it can be restated in such a way, if there is no medication change, the group will be determined by the number of month. Otherwise it will be determined by which month the medication is switched and if this is the case, you can accomplish it using `data.table` as following:

```
setDT(df)[, list({medSwitch = which(c(0, diff(med)) != 0);
                  Group = ifelse(length(medSwitch) == 0,
                                 ifelse(.N <= 4, .N - 1, 3),
                                 ifelse(min(medSwitch) <= 4, min(medSwitch) - 1, 3))}), .(ID)]
#    ID V1
# 1:  1  1
# 2:  2  3
# 3:  3  3
# 4:  4  2
# 5:  5  2
# 6:  6  3
# 7:  7  1
# 8:  8  3
```

If you are looking for in-place mutation, i.e. add the group to original data frame, instead of summary as above, you can do:

```
setDT(df)[, Group := list({medSwitch = which(c(0, diff(med)) != 0);
                           ifelse(length(medSwitch) == 0,
                                  ifelse(.N <= 4, .N - 1, 3),
                                  ifelse(min(medSwitch) <= 4, min(medSwitch) - 1, 3))}), .(ID)]
```

Note: The result matches your desired output but differs from the condition you defined at the beginning of your question. Possibly you mean `|` instead of `&`?

Comment: how you set nrow of group in data.table, I manage by this way,setDT(df)[ ,group := ifelse(lenght(ID) == 2,1,ifelse(lenght(ID) == 3,2,3)), by = ID]. i need only this one

Comment: You can use `.N` which represents the number of rows within each group. So `setDT(df)[, group := ifelse(.N == 2, 1, ifelse(.N == 3, 2, 3)), by = ID]` if that is what you need.

Comment: @Psidom Since `.N` is a scalar, `group := if (.N==2) 1 else if (.N==3) 2 else 3` should work (regarding your comment)

Comment: @Frank Right. That should be faster. Thanks for pointing that out! I was just following OP's logic.